# Blank cells in spreadsheet no longer blank when saved to desktop

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a java application that exports some data to a spreadsheet using POI. The problem is that sometimes (not always) there are a couple of lines that have no information (they are "blank") but when I save the XLS document to my desktop and open it, the cells are filled with the correct information.

Im using POI 3.7.

Down here you have an example of what's happening.

[image: Excel]

[EDIT] - I add some code:

This is the method that insert the data into the sheet:

```
public void setTransactionDetailsData(HSSFSheet sheet, String[][] records){
    HSSFRow rowContent = null;
    HSSFCell cellContent = null;        
    String cell = "";

    Integer recordNumber = records.length;
    Integer columnNumber = records[0].length;

    Integer nextDataIndex = 0;          

    String styleText = "";      

    boolean customStyles = styles.size()>0;

    short alignment;

    CellStyle cellStyle = null;

    for(int i = 0; i<recordNumber;i++){         
        //New row           
        rowContent = sheet.createRow(lastRowCreated);           
        rowContent.setHeightInPoints((customDataCellHeight * sheet.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints()));                         

        for(int j = 0; j<columnNumber;j++){

            cellContent = null;
            cellContent = rowContent.createCell((nextDataIndex));

            cell = records[i][j];   

            if(customStyles){
                try{
                    styleText = styles.get(nextDataIndex);
                    alignment = getAlignment(styleText);
                }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                    LOG.info("Error while obtaining style for position " +nextDataIndex+ ", max index is " +(styles.size()-1)+ ". Check the list of styles you send");
                    styleText = "";
                    alignment = 1;
                }
            }else{
                alignment = 1;
            }                   

            cellStyle = getCellStyle(i,Integer.valueOf(alignment),styleText);

            //Text
            if("".equals(styleText) || "value_left".equals(styleText) || "value".equalsIgnoreCase(styleText)){
                cellContent.setCellValue(cell);                     
            }else{
                if(isNumeric(cell)){                        
                    try{
                        cellContent.setCellValue(convertoToParseableNumber(cell));
                        cellContent.setCellType(0);
                    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                        LOG.info("Error ocurred while parsing value " +cell+ " no number");
                        cellContent.setCellValue(cell);
                    }                   
                }else{                      
                    cellContent.setCellValue(cell);
                }
            }       
            cellContent.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
            nextDataIndex++;                                
        }           
        //Back to first column              
        nextDataIndex = 0;
        lastRowCreated++;               
    }       
    autosize(sheet);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Apache POI? What happens when you upgrade?

Comment: Client requierement. Should I suggest a version upgrade?

Comment: I would first give it a try with the newer version to see if it actually changes anything and only then suggest an upgrade.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll try upgrading to a newer version and if it fix the problems, I will post it as a solution.

Comment: Hello, It didn't solve the problem. I go on the research and will post the solution as soon as I find it out. Thanks for the hints guys.